# Change location of backups in timeshift, specify a directory

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, docker

How do I change the location where timeshift keeps the backups of the system?

It is listing the drives and allows to choose between them, but there is no directory location as to where it should go on that drive.

The reason it matters to me is because it is choosing a totally random location to keep my system backups: My /home is a drive, I choose to keep my docker images out of my /root onto my /home at `/home/<user>/docker-images`.

Timeshift seems to think this as an appropriate location to keep my system backups, at: `/home/<user>/docker-images/aufs/timeshift/snapshot*`

I would like to move this out of the images directory. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Part of the question, timeshift burying my backups under docker image directory is because 'systems running docker are not supported by timeshift'. https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You must not run Timeshift on a system which has docker installed

---

After running out of free disk space, I figured out timeshift was wrongly storing its rsync snapshots under `/var/lib/docker/...`. You are not alone. A few issues exist mentioning this to the Timeshift devs:

- 2016-12-28 https://bugs.launchpad.net/timeshift/+bug/1652975
- 2017-10-21 https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/47
- 2017-11-19 https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/72
- 2018-01-31 https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/133
- 2018-03-18 https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/161

All issues were closed with the statement that Timeshift is not compatible with systems running docker.

2018-04-20 (Timeshift v18.4): the Timeshift [README.md](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/blob/v18.4/README.md#supported-system-configurations) file on Github states:

> ## Supported System Configurations
>
> ...
>
> - **Docker & Containers** - Docker and containerized systems are not supported. Running Timeshift on such systems will have unpredictable results.

Comment: One of the questions you linked to in the answer was raised by me on Github, same time as this question!

Comment: I seem to have a similar problem with `lxd` installed.

Comment: @JānisElmeris also see https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/227

Answer (score 1):

I ended up mounting an NFS on timeshift default dir

`192.168.7.77:/volume1/timeshift 3746074496 2680159488 1065915008  72% var/lib/docker/aufs/timeshift`

Also another option would be to simplink timeshift dir somwhere else. 
This options would work for rsynk.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to this party, but I think OP is asking where the prime Timeshift settings are located? Symlink-ing destination rsync doesn't work while Timeshift is active (has /run/timeshift/backup locked as busy), and I don't think it's a good idea to have chronjob scheduling in place if you have, like me, a 1TB external USB drive that I can walk around to several Linuxes and get a system snapshot.

[image: You can get to this screen by clicking the Setup wizard of Timeshift]. Then, as others have commented, turn off all scheduled backups if it's a one-time backup you're after on an external disk.